# Why is Mysql match boolean mode not finding "Knows"

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have these two queries

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE  MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('knows' in boolean mode )

SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE  MATCH(`title`) AGAINST('woman' in boolean mode )
```

and in the table I have a row with `title = "a woman knows"`

the first query finds that row, but the second doesn't!
I have experimented with different alternatives - for example, if the title contains "a woman knots" then querying for a match against "knots" works

I am mystified, so any help you can provide would be welcome.

Comment: Why don't you just use `LIKE` ? It's shorter and easier.

Comment: If you need to ignore stopwords (like "knows") you could try checking out this other [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678920/ignoring-mysql-fulltext-stopwords-in-query).

Comment: I would prefer to us 'like' but I need to let the user search for multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"knows" is a [stopword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and will not be indexed (and therefore ignored in all searches).
You can load your own list of stopwords with the [ft_stopword_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) server option.

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't realized the use of stop words in the match feature-- live and learn!