# Mysql match function

Tags: mysql

Fore some reasons mysql match doesn't find anything. I have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phrases` (
  `question` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `question` (`question`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `phrases` (`question`, `answer`) VALUES
('Hello Hello', 'Hello'),
('Hi', 'Hello'),
('Hola', 'Hello');
```

And when I try:

```
select match(question) against('Hello') from phrases
```

Results are zero. But what's interesting, if I try this:

```
select match(question) against('Hola') from phrases
```

It gives 0.6852666139602661 for question 'Hola'

Comment: Please format your post properly before hitting Submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because mysql full text search has a stop word list https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

which contains some common words which will be ignored for the search. Hence you are getting no result for `Hello`

If you want to disable that follow this for myisam engine [ignoring mysql fulltext stopwords in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678920/ignoring-mysql-fulltext-stopwords-in-query)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am making chat bot for online support and Hello was just first word I tried how it works, and it looked like nothing is working.