# MySQL Match Against: easiest way to deal with stopwords

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-indexing

I get zero results from this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `myTable` WHERE MATCH(tagline) AGAINST(' +IT professional' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I get 92 from this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `myTable` WHERE `tagline` LIKE '%IT professional%'
```

I prefer the first query because MATCH against an index is 80% faster with my setup. Obviously "IT" is a stopword and causing problems. What is the easiest and most expedient way of dealing with this problem if I want the functionality of the second query and the speed of the first one?

Comment: Would "remove the stopword list" be an option?

Comment: Yes, please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Would this do it:  SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF'; CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;  That way I don't need to worry about stopwords, the only downside is the increased time for searches.

Answer (score 1):

If `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is the default of `3`, then `IT` is "too short" (as opposed to "a stopword").  Further note that `+IT` insists on `IT`, but, since `IT` is totally ignored, it is never found.  Hence the "zero results".

I have had good success with this approach to arbitrary data coming from the user:  If the word is 3 or more characters long, prefix it with `+`, else leave it alone:

```
... AGAINST('it +professional' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That has the effect of ignoring "it" and finding all rows with "professional", "professionals", etc.

In some situations (perhaps not yours) this can be useful:

```
WHERE MATCH(fullname) AGAINST("+Rick +James" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND fullname LIKE "%Rick James%"
```

That works fast (because the fulltext is quite efficient and the LIKE is performed only against those that match the FT test).

And it avoids

```
... Rick Smith and James Davis ...
```

In your case, this *might* be appropriate:

```
WHERE MATCH(tagline) AGAINST('IT +professional' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND tagline LIKE '%IT +professional%'
```

The FT test finds all taglines with "professional" whether "IT" or not; the LIKE further filters.

Your "80% faster" says to me that the table is not very big.  The improvement for my tips grows with table size.

Comment: Yes, I am combining match with like in the way that you suggested to avoid the full table scan. 80% faster so far, on the small subset of the data that I've indexed so far. Looking good. I am guessing that I don't want to add quote marks because the bigram "information technology" will not be indexed, but those two individual words will be. I just need to make sure each word is preceded with a + symbol. I also need to find the setting in MySQL that deals with stopwords and turn it off. Any guidance on that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I don't happen to know the optimal way to deal with a bigram.  When searching for details on stopwords, make sure the advice is aimed at InnoDB, not MyISAM; there _are_ differences based on Engine.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help. One more quick question: Can I rebuild the table with this: SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF'; CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;

Comment: @NedHulton - Instead of `CREATE`, so `ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=InnoDB;`  That has the effect of rebuilding the indexes, but otherwise not really changing anything.

Comment: Right, I am adding the data again and starting from scratch with new indexes, I just want to be sure that stopwords are gone forever. I followed the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678920/ignoring-mysql-fulltext-stopwords-in-query. I've edited the my.cnf file I then just need to run this SQL command and I should be good? SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF';

Comment: @NedHulton - Correct.  The `CREATE ... LIKE ...` gives you an empty table.  The `SET` appies _until_ a restart; the change to my.cnf is noticed _afterwards_.  (I hope I have not missed some subtle point.  But you seem to know the main things.)

Comment: Not working... I'm asking a new question. Thanks again. Sincerely appreciated. Determined to defeat this issue...

Comment: New question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713886/mysql-fulltext-index-help-disable-stopwords Help massively appreciated. Driving me nuts.